# How to get the place search from google map

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have implemented a google map, on click on button app is redirected to google map of your phone, and marker points your current location.

Now I want when user search the place on google map i want to show it on screen, actually on textfield, but for meanwhile want to print it on console.

here is my code

```
class MapUtils {
  MapUtils._();

  static Future<void> openMap(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    String googleUrl =
        'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
    if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
      await launch(googleUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
    }
  }
}

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator();
  late Position _currentPosition;
  late String _currentAddress;


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    initUniqueIdentifierState();
    getImei();
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });

      _getAddressFromLatLng();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

_getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);

      Placemark place = p[0];
      print("lat long");
      print(_currentPosition.latitude);
      print(_currentPosition.longitude);

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
        print("${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DASHBOARD"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                MapUtils.openMap(
                    _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
              },
              child: Container(child: Text("go to google map")),
            ),
])));}
```

i got [this](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker/install)  package but it is not installing, give me versions issues on provider and http.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in streamlline_app...                 
Because google_maps_place_picker <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on provider ^4.0.1 and dynamic_app depends on provider ^6.0.1, google_maps_place_picker <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 is forbidden.
So, because dynamic_app depends on google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because dynamic_app depends on google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

Running "flutter pub get" in streamlline_app...                 
Because google_maps_place_picker <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http ^0.12.0+4 and dynamic_app depends on http ^0.13.4, google_maps_place_picker <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 is forbidden.
So, because dynamic_app depends on google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because dynamic_app depends on google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

please help how to do this.

Comment: This might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sL74UNLssV8

Comment: Are you using 1.0.1 or 2.0.0 version of google_maps_place_picker package? Did you try each version and still got the same issue?